# How many rows were updated by a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I created this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_put_question_responses] 
    @AnswerGridResponses     VARCHAR(20),   
    @UpdateRowCount     INT OUTPUT,
    @UserId             INT, 
    @UserTestQuestionId INT
AS
BEGIN   
   BEGIN        
      UPDATE  UserTestQuestion      
      SET     AnswerGridResponses = @AnswerGridResponses,
              Answered = 1
      WHERE   UserTestQuestionId = @UserTestQuestionId
      AND     UserId = @UserId
   END 
   SELECT @UpdateRowCount AS UpdateRowCount
END
```

I am calling it like this:

```
DECLARE @UpdateRowCount     INT;

exec dbo.sp_put_question_responses '1000',
                              @UpdateRowCount OUT,
                              '2',      
                              '3249'

SELECT @UpdateRowCount

SELECT userid, UserTestQuestionId from Usertestquestion
where  UserTestQuestionId = '3249'
```

But it is not giving me the correct value for the updated rows count:

```
UpdateRowCount
--------------
NULL

userid      UserTestQuestionId
----------- ------------------
2           3249
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about using @@ROWCOUNT?

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Comment: Yes, @@RowCount would yield the correct number after the DML statement execution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting `@UpdateRowCount` to anything, you're simply passing back the empty value. You can use `@@ROWCOUNT` to return the number of rows affected by a SQL statement like so:

```
SET @UpdateRowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Reference:

[@@ROWCOUNT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. If the number of rows is more than 2 billion, use ROWCOUNT_BIG.

Comment: Could I simplify further and do:  SELECT @ROWCOUNT AS UpdateRowCount ?

Comment: @Alan not really with your existing code, as `@UpdateRowCount` is an output parameter, so you need to set that parameter to get the value out of your stored proc. If you remove the output parameter, you can do this and the row count would be returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_put_question_responses] 
    @AnswerGridResponses     VARCHAR(20),   
    @UpdateRowCount     INT OUTPUT,
    @UserId             INT, 
    @UserTestQuestionId INT
AS
BEGIN   

      UPDATE  UserTestQuestion      
      SET     AnswerGridResponses = @AnswerGridResponses,
              Answered = 1
      WHERE   UserTestQuestionId = @UserTestQuestionId
      AND     UserId = @UserId
  SET @UpdateRowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
   SELECT @UpdateRowCount AS UpdateRowCount
END
```